# Join or Merge Pandas Dataframes filling null values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes - `Deployment` and `HPA` as shown. Both dataframes mostly share the values in columns `Deployment-Label` and `HPA-Label` which need to merge/join by filling-up null values in all other columns in both dataframes (wherever the values are missing in either of columns `Deployment-Label` and `HPA-Label`.)

Tried using `pd.merge`, but the it is dropping the non-common rows in both df.

```py
# Merge the two dataframes, using LABEL common col, after renaming
df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, on = 'LABEL')

# Write it to a new CSV file
df3.to_csv('output/merged.csv')
```

| Deployment-Label | Deployment Table - Other Columns |
| --- | --- |
| accountdataservice | 1 |
| accountservice-grpc | 2 |
| fmsdataservice | 3 |
| fuelbenchmarkservice-grpc | 4 |
| fueldeviationservice-grpc | 5 |
| httpclientservice | 6 |
| packageservice-grpc | 7 |
| provisioningdataservice | 8 |
| traefik-ingress-ilb | 9 |
| translationservice-grpc | 10 |

| HPA-Label | HPA Table - Other Columns |
| --- | --- |
| accountdataservice | A |
| accountservice-grpc | B |
| fmsdataservice | C |
| fuelbenchmarkservice-grpc | D |
| fueldeviationservice-grpc | E |
| hangfire | F |
| httpclientservice | G |
| packageservice-grpc | H |
| portalservicerest | I |
| provisioningdataservice | J |
| schedularservice-grpc | K |
| translationservice-grpc | L |

### Expected Outcome:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass `how="outer"` and `sort=True` as *keyword arguments* to [`pd.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge.html) :

```
df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, on = "LABEL", how="outer", sort=True)

#or given your MRE, use df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on="Deployment-Label",
#                                     right_on = "HPA-Label", how="outer", sort=True)
```

​Output :

```
print(df3)

             Deployment-Label  Deployment Table - Other Columns                  HPA-Label HPA Table - Other Columns
0          accountdataservice                               1.0         accountdataservice                         A
1         accountservice-grpc                               2.0        accountservice-grpc                         B
2              fmsdataservice                               3.0             fmsdataservice                         C
3   fuelbenchmarkservice-grpc                               4.0  fuelbenchmarkservice-grpc                         D
4   fueldeviationservice-grpc                               5.0  fueldeviationservice-grpc                         E
5                         NaN                               NaN                   hangfire                         F
6           httpclientservice                               6.0          httpclientservice                         G
7         packageservice-grpc                               7.0        packageservice-grpc                         H
8                         NaN                               NaN          portalservicerest                         I
9     provisioningdataservice                               8.0    provisioningdataservice                         J
10                        NaN                               NaN      schedularservice-grpc                         K
11        traefik-ingress-ilb                               9.0                        NaN                       NaN
12    translationservice-grpc                              10.0    translationservice-grpc                         L
```